# ASP.NET Boilerplate Service 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProviderIsService' not registered

Tags: asp.net, boilerplate

I just updated my visual studio so I could create a new project in .net 8, but now I'm getting the following error in my existing boilerplate 8.1.0 project:

'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionProvider_26c5b40a-354d-4734-90cd-1b6d59e8e3d1' is waiting for the following dependencies:

- Service 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceProviderIsService' which was not registered.

No changes were made to the project and it ran with no issue prior to updating visual studio

1. Delete .vs folder
2. Clean and rebuild solution

Comment: Try deleting bin and obj folders for all the projects in the solution. Usually that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue where the error occurred only when running the project via Visual Studio and not when using `dotnet run` directly. This led me to suspect that the issue may be related to Visual Studio itself. I would recommend trying the following steps:

1. **Repair Visual Studio**: Perform a repair on your Visual Studio installation to ensure that all components are correctly configured.
2. **Downgrade Visual Studio**: If the issue persists, consider downgrading Visual Studio to a previous version. This can help identify if the problem is specific to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when I update the ABP Version to 8.3 [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ac4E.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I found myself in the same situation as you and the only solution I found was to rollback the VS version from 17.9.0 to 17.8.6 (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-visual-studio-rollback/)